# Equivalent Wyckoff position in different groups

Tags: symmetry, group-theory, crystallography

I am not a chemist, I am a physicist, so please bare with me if what I am asking is rather obvious.

If I have two symmetry groups ($P4/mmm$ and $P\!-\!1$), is there a way to find their respective Wyckoff positions for which they are equivalent? Meaning finding the Wyckoff position for each of those groups, so that those positions in specific share the same symmetries. Hopefully I made myself clear.

I really doubt it's as easy as to look at the Wyckoff groups symmetries but I don't know.